# Error with Mysql 5.7 : mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

So I am trying to run this code

```
if file == '' :
    authorization_id = 0
    try :
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='******', password='******',
                                      host='**************************',
                                      port='*****',
                                      database='Test')
        
    except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError:
        print("Impossible Server Connection :/")
        sys.exit()

    cur = cnx.cursor()
        
    numbers = '0123456789'
    player_id = ''


    for x in range(25) :
        player_id+=(numbers[random.randint(0,9)])     
    
    with open("Player_id.txt","w") as file :
        file.write(player_id)
        list_player_id = []
        list_player_id.append(player_id)
        player_id = list_player_id

    cur.execute(('''INSERT INTO best_score(user_id) VALUES (?)'''),player_id)
    cnx.commit()
    cur.close()if file == '' :
    authorization_id = 0
    try :
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password',
                                      host='hostname',
                                      port='portname',
                                      database='Test')
        
    except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError:
        print("Impossible Server Connection :/")
        sys.exit()

    cur = cnx.cursor()
        
    numbers = '0123456789'
    player_id = ''


    for x in range(25) :
        player_id+=(numbers[random.randint(0,9)])     
    
    with open("Player_id.txt","w") as file :
        file.write(player_id)
        list_player_id = []
        list_player_id.append(player_id)
        player_id = list_player_id

    cur.execute(('''INSERT INTO best_score(user_id) VALUES (?)'''),player_id)
    cnx.commit()
    cur.close()`
```

But I get this error, do u have any ideas ???

```
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
    mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: You get this error where?

Comment: @user207421 when i run the program

Comment: No kidding. I was thinking you got it while walking the dog. Get serious, please. Which line of code gives this error?

Comment: @user207421 haha ok so it gives me this error at the line : cur.execute(('''INSERT INTO best_score(user_id) VALUES (?)'''),player_id)

Comment: @user207421 2 lines ?

Comment: At least. Try searching for that string. Two occurrences in the code you posted. But the error must surely come from *another* such line where you haven't provided the argument.

Comment: Actually I typed in the shell the value that i want to save in my db and it returns me that : ['0183576964235371189066284'], so this is not an empty argument.

Comment: Actually the error message doesn't agree with you, and actually you still haven't told us which exact line of code gave that error, or whether there are any more like it. Error messages do not lie.

Comment: @user207421 dont worry i finnaly solved the problem ;)

Comment: I'm not exactly worried ;-) but you should either post your solution or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the execution of cursor. You need to pass a tuple (or list) of elements, and you only pass one element.
You should do your cur. execute this way:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO best_score(user_id) VALUES (?)''',(player_id,))
```

Besides that, your code seems duplicated, as you open two times the same file and open two times the Mysql connection